# How to avoid reload after php code execution?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page in my online game... where when a users wins a battle, he is rewarded with certain amount of **Money** and **Exp**
So I use update query to update the database with the new value:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon_db SET exp = exp + ".round($experience)." WHERE id = ".$pokeid[$value].";") or die(mysql_error());
```

This code is written on `finish.php`

But the problem is..when I reload the page...the update query is executed again...! and it goes on, till I keep pressing reload.
Logically its right! but I want to avoid resending of data through reload!!
How should I avoid the updating of data on reload..??? Is there any way?

Comment: I want to use PHP. Cause I am use to it. I haven't learned ajax. any solution in PHP?

Comment: You should not just write the update query.
You should put inside some kind of if condition.

Like set a session whenever the exp or money changes and in the if condition check for that session and run your update query and unset that session

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ohkk but what would be the condition? i mean any logic? means how will I know user have played a genuine game and is not reloading?

Comment: @ThiefMaster thats a good point.

Comment: @user3672971 comment updated.

Comment: You could do a redirect after the mysql update:   header('Location: /someotherpage.php');

Comment: The immediate answer to your problem is the linked duplicate. The broader problem of how to avoid people being able to cheat by making arbitrary requests to your server is a much broader one, and not one to which there's a general solution. You need sanity checks on your server for everything, how exactly that needs to look depends on your app.

Comment: Yaa got it Tousif thanks alot! I unset all the sessions.. associated with the query :) thnks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few, but most times using a $_SESSION is the best option.
Just set a property when your script should update.
say:

```
$_SESSION['mustUpdateExperience']=true;
```

Check for this flag before updating, and set it to false when the update completed.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mustUpdateExperience'])&&$_SESSION['mustUpdateExperience']===true){
   mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon_db SET exp = exp + ".round($experience)." WHERE id = ".$pokeid[$value].";") or die(mysql_error());
   $_SESSION['mustUpdateExperience']=false;
 }
```

Comment: Thnks for the logic! I got some idea after reading this! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, 
set some flag in db table expressing its status, that could be validated on later reloads.

Second,
To avoid reloads, don't let user have the url to hit upon.

Third, 
Have a flag on client side also, which avoids unnecessary reloading by disabling the url/button of the post.